# Javafx Custom Tooltip Implementation Only Shows on Last Node Installed

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to create my own Tooltip implementation, that has an arrow and shows the tooltip on a certain side of the node it's installed on. 
It looks like this: 
[image]

Here's what i've coded so far

> Tooltip.java

```
public class Tooltip extends PopupControl {

    private StringProperty message = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final static TooltipSkin skin = new TooltipSkin();
    private final static TooltipBehavior behavior = new TooltipBehavior();

    public Tooltip(Node node, String message) {
        this.message.setValue(message);
        if (getContent() != skin.createSkin()) {
            getContent().setAll(skin.createSkin());
        }
        behavior.install(node, Tooltip.this);
    }

    /****************************************************************
     **********                  ACCESSORS               ************
     ****************************************************************/

    String getMessage() {
        return message.get();
    }

    StringProperty messageProperty() {
        return message;
    }

    private static class TooltipBehavior {
        final String TOOLTIP_PROP_KEY = "fxtooltip";

        private void install(Node node, Tooltip tooltip) {
            if (node == null)
                return;
            node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED, ENTERED_HANDLER);
            node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_EXITED, KILL_HANDLER);
            node.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, KILL_HANDLER);
            node.getProperties().put(TOOLTIP_PROP_KEY, tooltip);
        }

        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> ENTERED_HANDLER = (MouseEvent event) -> {
            Node hoveredNode = (Node) event.getSource();
            Tooltip tooltip = ((Tooltip) hoveredNode.getProperties().get(TOOLTIP_PROP_KEY));
            String message = tooltip.getMessage();
            skin.setMessage(message);
            tooltip.show(getWindow(hoveredNode), 0, 0);
        };
        private EventHandler<MouseEvent> KILL_HANDLER = (MouseEvent event) -> {
            Node hoveredNode = (Node) event.getSource();
            Tooltip tooltip = ((Tooltip) hoveredNode.getProperties().get(TOOLTIP_PROP_KEY));
            tooltip.hide();
        };

        private Window getWindow(final Node node) {
            final Scene scene = node == null ? null : node.getScene();
            return scene == null ? null : scene.getWindow();
        }
    }

    private static class TooltipSkin {
        private static HBox $RootView = new HBox();
        private static StackPane $PaneMessageBody = new StackPane();
        private static StackPane $PaneArrow = new StackPane();
        private static Text $TextMessage = new Text();
        private static boolean skinInitialized = false;

        Pane createSkin() {
            if (skinInitialized) {
                return $RootView;
            } else {
                skinInitialized = true;
                $RootView.getChildren().addAll($PaneMessageBody, $PaneArrow);
                $PaneMessageBody.getChildren().addAll($TextMessage);
            }
            return $RootView;
        }

        void setMessage(String message) {
            $TextMessage.setText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

> In my controller, I have some buttons i added tooltips to this way

```
new Tooltip($BtnDownload, "Download");
new Tooltip($BtnActivate, "Activate");
```

However, this only works on the **last node** a tooltip is installed on, If i hover over other nodes that have a tooltip, cursor **starts flickering,** and the tooltip doesn't show at all. What could the issue be here?

Comment: Suggestion: to help others answer your questions better, consider creating a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate your problem in a shorter format.

Comment: Thanks, Should i include trivials. like creating an app class, a controller and a view? If not, what do you see i can add here?

Comment: It's not really what you can _add_; as it stands, your post contains a lot of code that most people don't really want to read through. The purpose of a mcve is  to make your question shorter, so that people can spend less time reading code and more time coming up with a solution.

Comment: Ah, got it thank you :)

Comment: Two things: 1). You've tagged your post [javafx-8] and [javafx-2]. I assume you're not using both, so please remove the tag of the version you are not using. 2). For the nodes where the cursor starts flickering, check to see whether or not your `KILL_HANDLER` is called immediately after the `MOVE_HANDLER`. It is possible that the tooltip is appearing on top of the node, causing the mouse to "move out" of the node.

Comment: Removed the tag, i checked the behavior of the kill handler with print statements and indeed, the ENTERED_HANDLER was called  then the KILL_HANDLER multiple times per mouse hover, but the last to be called was the ENTERED_HANDLER, yet no tooltip showed. Kinda confusing how it works just fine on the node that had a tooltip installed.

Comment: "*Should i include trivials. like creating an app class, a controller and a view?*" Yes, it's the C in MCVE. If we can't copy-paste and run it (and see the problem), it's not a MCVE.

Comment: You are using some `static` fields, so that might be it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i made the field static as i only wanted only 1 tooltip view to be created and change its text according to which tooltip is active, that gave me a lot of issues, so i ended up creating a new tooltip skin object for each tooltip, which weirdly solved the issue. Not sure that's the most performant way though.

Comment: Well, as you were told, create a [mcve] and the question will be answerable without guesswork. Also, use @username to reply in comments.

Comment: @user1803551
Sorry, i solved it before i got a chance to create an mcve. I will post the answer soon.